# Числа Фибоначчи

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика, числа-фибоначчи

- Что такое числа Фибоначчи?
- Как найти первые `n` чисел Фибоначчи?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Определение чисел Фибоначчи

[Числа Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8) это последовательность натуральных чисел, которая начинается с чисел ноль и один, а каждое следующее число равно сумме двух предыдущих:

- [image: F_0 = 0]
- [image: F_1 = 1]
- [image: F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}]

Первые 10 чисел Фибоначчи:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
```

### Получение первых `n` чисел Фибоначчи

Чтобы найти первые `n` чисел Фибоначчи, можно создать массив размера `n`, первые два элемента будут равны нулю и единице, а остальные элементы можно получить, используя цикл и вышеприведённую формулу:

```
int[] f = new int[n];
f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
    f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
}
```

В коде предполагается существование переменной `n`, которую можно ввести с клавиатуры, например так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
```

После заполнения массива `f` полученные первые `n` чисел Фибоначчи можно вывести на экран с помощью цикла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    System.out.println(f[i]);
}
```

[Онлайн пример кода](https://ideone.com/UAe8sg)

Стоит заметить, что тип `int` в Java позволяет хранить только числа до 2<sup>31</sup>-1, поэтому вышеприведённым способом получится вычислить только первые 46 чисел Фибоначчи (при [попытке вычислить сорок седьмое число Фибоначчи](https://ideone.com/TY8NqL) произойдёт [переполнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и получится отрицательное число). Используя тип данных `long` вместо `int` без переполнения получится вычислить первые 91 число Фибоначчи. Чтобы вычислять последующие числа Фибоначчи [можно воспользоваться](https://ideone.com/0eQ9DG) классом [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), который реализует [длинную арифметику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) в Java.

### Получения `n`-ого по счёту числа Фибоначчи

Для получения только `n`-ого числа Фибоначчи не обязательно использовать массив, достаточно завести две переменных `a` и `b`, в которых будут храниться последние два числа Фибоначчи, и пересчитывать эти переменные `n - 2` раза:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    int next = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = next;
}
System.out.println(b);
```

[Онлайн пример кода](https://ideone.com/WXTafM)

### Рекурсивное вычисление чисел Фибоначчи

Существует также рекурсивный способ вычисления чисел Фибоначчи. Однако его не рекомендуется использовать, потому что, в отличии от предыдущих двух способов, которые работают за линейное время от `n`, рекурсивный способ может работать значительно дольше.

```
// функция, возвращающая n-ое число Фибоначчи
public static int f(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }
}
```

[Онлайн пример кода](https://ideone.com/2Q4SX9)

Рекурсивный способ работает за экспоненциальное время от `n`, например для `n` равного 46 рекурсивный способ [работает дольше пяти секунд](https://ideone.com/yFAu3J), а способ с запоминанием последних двух чисел Фибоначчи [работает менее одной десятой секунды](https://ideone.com/NFVEmL)).

Рекурсивный способ может работать долго, потому что в процессе вычисления функция будет много раз вызываться от одного и того же аргумента (например, при вычислении `f(5)` функция сделает рекурсивные вызовы к `f(4)` и `f(3)`, оба рекурсивных вызова обратятся к `f(2)`), что приведёт к многократному повторению одних и тех же операций.

### Быстрое вычисление чисел Фибоначчи с помощью быстрого умножения матриц (используя `O(log n)` операций умножения)

Рассмотрим матрицу:

[image: матрица [[1, 1], [1, 0]]]

Используя [матричное умножение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86), рекуррентное соотношение для последних двух чисел Фибоначчи может быть записано так:

[image: рекуррентное соотношение для последних двух чисел Фибоначчи в матричной форме]

Расписывая это соотношение, получаем:

[image: матричное выражение последних двух чисел Фибоначчи]

Таким образом, чтобы найти `n`-ое число Фибоначчи достаточно возвести матрицу `A` в степень `n - 1`. Это можно сделать [алгоритмом быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

```
// матричное умножение двух матриц размера 2 на 2
public static BigInteger[][] matrixMultiplication(BigInteger[][] a, BigInteger[][] b) {
    // [a00 * b00 + a01 * b10, a00 * b01 + a01 * b11]
    // [a10 * b00 + a11 * b10, a10 * b01 + a11 * b11]
    return new BigInteger[][]{
            {a[0][0].multiply(b[0][0]).add(a[0][1].multiply(b[1][0])), a[0][0].multiply(b[0][1]).add(a[0][1].multiply(b[1][1]))},
            {a[1][0].multiply(b[0][0]).add(a[1][1].multiply(b[1][0])), a[1][0].multiply(b[0][1]).add(a[1][1].multiply(b[1][1]))},
    };
}

// возведение матрицы размера 2 на 2 в степень n
public static BigInteger[][] matrixPowerFast(BigInteger[][] a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        // любая матрица в нулевой степени равна единичной матрице
        return new BigInteger[][]{
                {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO},
                {BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}
        };
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        // a ^ (2k) = (a ^ 2) ^ k
        return matrixPowerFast(matrixMultiplication(a, a), n / 2);
    } else {
        // a ^ (2k + 1) = (a) * (a ^ 2k)
        return matrixMultiplication(matrixPowerFast(a, n - 1), a);
    }
}

// функция, возвращающая n-ое число Фибоначчи
public static BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }

    BigInteger[][] a = {
            {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE},
            {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO}
    };
    BigInteger[][] powerOfA = matrixPowerFast(a, n - 1);
    // nthFibonacci = powerOfA[0][0] * F_1 + powerOfA[0][0] * F_0 = powerOfA[0][0] * 1 + powerOfA[0][0] * 0
    BigInteger nthFibonacci = powerOfA[0][0];
    return nthFibonacci;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fibonacci(1024));
}
```

[Онлайн пример кода](https://ideone.com/O08Sqk)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу @diralik

**Быстрое вычисление без матриц**

Степени матрицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения] можно выразить через числа Фибоначчи. Нетрудно показать по индукции, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это выражение даёт нам формулы удвоения индекса числа Фибоначчи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта формула реализована в коде ниже в методе `Fib.fast(int)`.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fib {
    public BigInteger next_ = BigInteger.ONE;
    public BigInteger current_ = BigInteger.ZERO;
    public int n = 0;

    public Fib next() {
        BigInteger tmp = next_.add(current_);
        current_ = next_;
        next_ = tmp;
        n++;
        return this;
    }

    public static Fib slow(int n) {
        var result = new Fib();
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result.next();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Fib fast(int n) {
        if (n < 16) {
            return Fib.slow(n);
        } 

        var result = Fib.fast(n/2);
        result.n *= 2;
        // F_{2n+1} = F_{n+1}**2 + F_{n}**2
        var _next = result.next_.multiply(result.next_).add(result.current_.multiply(result.current_));
        // F_{2n} = (2*F_{n+1} - F_{n})*F_{n}
        var _current = (result.next_.add(result.next_).subtract(result.current_)).multiply(result.current_);
        result.next_ = _next;
        result.current_ = _current;
        if (n%2 == 1) {
            result.next();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Оценка через золотое сечение**

Для чисел Фибоначчи есть [формула Бине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5), которая вычисляет числа Фибоначчи без итерации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как числа Фибоначчи довольно быстро выходят за пределы типа `double`, для оценки числа Фибоначчи через формулу Бине я использую `BigDecimal` с округлением до 20 значащих цифр. Такое округление даёт 10 правильных цифр в результате.

```
    private static final MathContext _mc = new MathContext(20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    private static final double _sqrt5 = Math.sqrt(5);
    public static final BigDecimal Sqrt5 = new BigDecimal(_sqrt5, _mc);
    public static final BigDecimal Phi = new BigDecimal((1 + _sqrt5)/2, _mc);

    public static BigDecimal estimate(int n) {
        return Phi.pow(n, _mc).divide(Sqrt5, _mc);
    }
```

**Сравнение скорости**

Быстрая формула вычисления чисел Фибоначчи использует три умножения на каждой итерации. Но благодаря тому, что число итераций растёт как логарифм `n`, общее время счёта по быстрой формуле в разы меньше, чем по классической формуле.

Ниже приведены сравнения результатов для `n=100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000`. Время в миллисекундах. `Estimate` - это как раз оценка по формуле Бине.

```
Slow: 100: 0.3249 (ms)
Fast: 100: 0.0736 (ms)
As double: 100: 3.5422484817E+20
Estimate : 100: 3.5422484817926308651E+20
Slow: 1000: 0.4168 (ms)
Fast: 1000: 0.1707 (ms)
As double: 1000: 4.3466557686E+208
Estimate : 1000: 4.3466557686938912905E+208
Slow: 10000: 5.604 (ms)
Fast: 10000: 1.526 (ms)
As double: 10000: 3.3644764876E+2089
Estimate : 10000: 3.3644764876443071607E+2089
Slow: 100000: 231.6341 (ms)
Fast: 100000: 8.0684 (ms)
As double: 100000: 2.5974069347E+20898
Estimate : 100000: 2.5974069347308882558E+20898
Slow: 1000000: 15967.3608 (ms)
Fast: 1000000: 89.9357 (ms)
As double: 1000000: 1.9532821287E+208987
Estimate : 1000000: 1.9532821287733027741E+208987
```

В выводе используется функция `asFloatString`, которая для большого целого строит приблизительное представление в виде вещественного числа

```
    private static String asFloatString(BigInteger bint, int ndig) {
        var _full = bint.toString(10);
        var s = _full.substring(0, ndig+1);
        s = s.substring(0,1) + "." + s.substring(1) + "E+" + (_full.length()-1);
        return s;
    }
```