# Объясните однострочник Python

Tags: python

Решил задачку на [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-fibonacci-numbers/forum?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=recursion-backtracking). Задачка такова: на вход подается число `n`, нужно вывести число Фибоначчи с порядковым номером n

В дискуссиях нашел вот такой пример:

```
fib = lambda n:pow(2<<n,n+1,(4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1)%(2<<n)
print(fib(int(input())))
```

Результат у этого кода правильный, но как он работает я решительно не понимаю

Comment: << Сдвиг влево Сдвигает биты числа влево на заданное количество позиций. /похоже  это магия низкого уровня

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37509291

Comment: Ну про сдвиг влево мне известно), зачем он тут нужен непонятно, как это работает, какой логике следовал автор этого шедевра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> lambda n:pow(2<<n,n+1,(4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1)%(2<<n)
> ```

#### по поводу синтаксических конструкций:

- синтаксис выражения [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda): `"lambda" [параметры] ":" выражение`. т.е.:
- `n` — это параметр
- `pow(2<<n,n+1,(4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1)%(2<<n)` — выражение
- `pow(base, exp[, mod])` — синтаксис [функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=pow#pow), которая производит возведение `base` в степень `exp` с опциональным делением по модулю на `mod` (т.е., получаем остаток от деления на `mod`).
- `2<<n` — это аргумент `base`
- `n+1` — это аргумент `exp`
- `(4<<2*n)-(2<<n)-1` — это аргумент `mod`
- `x<<y` — операция [бинарного сдвига](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bitwise#shifting-operations), эквиватент: `x * 2 ** y`, а для `2<<n` эквивалет: `2 ** (n + 1)`.
- `4<<2*n` — операция сдвига имеет более низкий приоритет, чем умножение, потому эквивалент: `4 * 2 ** (2 * n)`, или иначе: `2 ** (2 * n + 2)`

#### теперь по поводу *общего* смысла выражения:

остаток от деления 2<sup>(n+1)<sup>(n+1)</sup></sup> на 2<sup>(2*n+2)</sup>-2<sup>(n+1)</sup>-1 делим ещё раз на 2<sup>(n+1}</sup>, результатом будет остаток от второго деления.

#### *математический* же смысл

стоит услышать из уст [автора](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37509291/4827341) первоначальной:

[An integer formula for Fibonacci numbers. by Paul Hankin](https://blog.paulhankin.net/fibonacci/)

и промежуточной версий:

[Fun with Fibonacci numbers. by Fare Rideau](http://fare.tunes.org/files/fun/fibonacci.lisp)

#### отчасти схожие вопросы:

- [Числа Фибоначчи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749177/178576)
- [Числа Фибоначчи. Объяснить код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972640/178576)